# C - checking if strings contain any non-null characters

Tags: c, if-statement, c-strings, function-definition, null-pointer

I have a function with two strings parameters. I have to check if both strings contains any non-null characters. Here is an example code:

```
void fun(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    if (!str1 || !str1[0] || !str2 || !str2[0])
    {
        return;
    }

    // process
}
```

Is that a standard approach in C or you recommend other solution ?

Comment: You may have a look at [strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)

Comment: A *string* containing any non-null character will contain it as a first character. Your code looks OK to me if your pointers can be `NULL` by themselves. `strlen` would be overkill here and also won't work for `NULL` pointers.

Comment: Depending on what the function does, checking that each string is non-zero length may be a redundant edge case that you do not need to check.  Validating that the pointers are not null is fine, but you should probably refactor the code so that you don't need to check the edge case.  But it's hard to say without knowing the purpose of the function.

Comment: "Is that a standard approach in C" --> It is  not a standard practice to test if a function parameter that points  to  a string contains any non-null characters.  Standard practice is to work with the string, even if `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to write the condition like

```
if ( !str1[0] || !str2[0] )
```

that is when the function follows the convention of C Standard string functions when passing a null-pointer invokes undefined behavior.

It is the caller of the function that shall guarantee that the passed pointers are not null pointers.

Comment: or `if (str1[0] && str2[0]) { work(); } /* else { chill(); } */` if you dislike negations :-)

Comment: @pmg "if you dislike negations" --> "if you like affirmation" ;-)

Comment: I like your wording better than mine, @chux, thanks